# Merging csv files with different headers with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to map a dataset to a blank CSV file with different headers, so I'm essentially trying to map data from one CSV file which has different headers to a new CSV with different amount of headers and called different things, the reason this question is different is since the column names aren't the same but there are no overlapping columns either. And I can't overwrite the data file with new headers since the data file has other columns with irrelevant data, I'm certain I'm overcomplicating this.

I've seen this example code but how do I change this since this example is using a common header to join the data.

```
a = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("b.csv")
#a.csv = ID TITLE
#b.csv = ID NAME
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on='title')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

***Sample Data***

a.csv (blank format file, the format must match this file):

```
Headers: TOWN NAME LOCATION HEIGHT STAR
```

b.csv:

```
Headers: COUNTRY WEIGHT  NAME  AGE MEASUREMENT
 Data:    UK,     150lbs, John, 6,  6ft
```

Expected output file:

```
Headers: TOWN    NAME   LOCATION  HEIGHT  STAR
Data:    (Blank) John,  UK,       6ft    (Blank)
```

Comment: Can you add in your sample data with your expected output?

Comment: @Datanovice The sample data is the bottom section, a.csv with only headers (the file format I need), b.csv is the data with different headers which I need to take and map to a.csv,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, it looks like you need to do some column renaming in addition to the `merge`. This is easiest done before the `merge` itself.

```
# Read the csv files
dfA = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
dfB = pd.read_csv("b.csv")

# Rename the columns of b.csv that should match the ones in a.csv
dfB = dfB.rename(columns={'MEASUREMENT': 'HEIGHT', 'COUNTRY': 'LOCATION'})

# Merge on all common columns
df = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on=list(set(dfA.columns) & set(dfB.columns)), how='outer')

# Only keep the columns that exists in a.csv
df = df[dfA.columns]

# Save to a new csv
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

This should give you what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using `df.reindex` to add the empty columns rather than `merge`.

```
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.read_csv('./a.csv')
dfb = pd.read_csv('./b.csv')

# These columns will be renamed.
colmap = {'COUNTRY': 'LOCATION', 'MEASUREMENT': 'HEIGHT'}
# Extract all unique column names.
cols = list(set(dfa.columns.tolist() + dfb.columns.tolist()))
# Create a new dataset matching requirements.
dfb = dfb.rename(columns=colmap).reindex(columns=cols)[dfa.columns]
# Write to CSV.
dfb.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

#### Output:

Content of the CSV as show from the console ...

```
(py35) user@host ~/Desktop/so
$ cat output.csv 

TOWN,NAME,LOCATION,HEIGHT,STAR
,John,UK,6ft
```

#### Source files:

Content of the source CSV files as show from the console ...

```
(py35) user@host ~/Desktop/so
$ cat a.csv 

TOWN,NAME,LOCATION,HEIGHT,STAR

(py35) user@host ~/Desktop/so
$ cat b.csv 

COUNTRY,WEIGHT,NAME,AGE,MEASUREMENT
UK,150lbs,John,6,6ft
```

Comment: This works for the column headers but the values aren't in the output file, so the result from your code gives me TOWN,NAME,LOCATION,HEIGHT,STAR   with nothing in the results

Comment: @MFDOOM - Maybe try again.  I've just run this myself and the content is there.  I've updated the answer to show a `cat` command run from the console showing the content of the CSV.  I've also added the content of my source files.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify left_on column for  a dataframe and right_on column for b dataframe. So you have common data type with header "data_1" on a and common data in b with header "data_2". If you don't create a series on these dataframes with simply a['series_1'] = [i for i in range(a.shape[0])] and for b ==> b['series_1] = [i for i in range(b.shape[0]). Right now you have a common column. If not you can use a.merge(b,left_on='a_column',right_on='b_column') this will work. You can use reset_index() for common column. Using a = a.reset_index() will create an index from 1 to a.shape[0] and use it for b = b.reset_index(). merge() function automatically understand the common data types with same headers.

Comment: Could you expand, please?